# Pass user specified parameters to DataLoader

Tags: pytorch, parameter-passing, dataloader

I am using U - Net and implementing the weighting technique described in the papers from 2015 (U-Net: Convolutional Networks for Biomedical
Image Segmentation) and 2019 (U-Net – Deep Learning for Cell Counting, Detection, and Morphometry). In that technique there is a variance σ and a weight w_0. I would like, especially the σ, to be a learnable parameter instead of guessing which value is best from dataset to dataset.

1. From what I found, I can do this using nn.Parameter.
2. To use the learned σ from epoch to epoch, I need somehow to pass this new value to the get_item function of the DataSet through the DataLoader.

My current take on this, is to extend torch.utils.data.DataLoader where the new **init** has an extra parameter accepting the user specified/learnable parameters. Given the source code of torch.utils.data.DataLoader, I do not understand where and how the DataLoader calls the DataSet instance and hence to pass these parameters.

Code wise, in the DataSet definition there is the function

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
```

that I can change as

```
def __getitem__(self, index, sigma):
```

and to make use of the updated, newly learned σ.

My problem is that during training, I iterate through training dataset as

```
for epoch in range( checkpoint[ 'epoch'], num_epochs):
....
    for ii, ( X, y, y_weight, fname) in enumerate( dataLoader[ phase]):
```

In that enumeration of DataLoader, how can I pass the new σ to the DataLoader such that the DataLoader will pass it to the DataSet **getitem** function mentioned above?

**EDIT**

Currently, I define inside the DataSet class a parameter *sigma*

```
class MedicalImageDataset( Dataset):
      def __init__(self, fname, img_transform = None, mask_transform = None, weight_transform = None, sigma = 8):
            ...
            self.sigma = sigma

      def __getitem__(self, index):
            sigma = self.sigma
            ...
```

which I update through the DataLoader as

```
dataLoader[ 'train'].dataset.sigma = model.sigma
```

where,

```
model.sigma
```

is a custom parameter defined as

```
model.register_parameter( name = 'sigma', param = torch.nn.Parameter( torch.tensor( 16, dtype = torch.float16), requires_grad = True))
```

after creating the model.

My problem is, that `model.sigma` doesn't look being updated from epoch to epoch. Specifically, is the same as the initial value. Why is this?

Having a look at `optimizer.state_dict()` I couldn't find any parameter named 'sigma', whereas I can find one in `model.named_parameters()`.

Finally, this parameter *sigma* is not attached to any layer, it's kinda "free".

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do is to set sigma as an attribute of the Dataset and change it between epochs.

For the dataset definition

```
class UNetDataset(object):
    def __init__(self, ..., sigma=5):

        self.sigma = sigma
```

Now, within `__getitem__`, you can use the sigma value using `self.sigma`

Now within your training cycle, after every epoch, you can change the sigma value by setting the sigma attribute of the Dataset

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    dataset.sigma = #whatever value you want

    for i,(x,y) in enumarate(DataLoader):
```

Comment: Say that I have initially σ = 3 and after the 1st epoch, σ = 5 after back propagation. Then at the 2nd epoch when I will be doing for ii, ( X, y, y_weight, fname) in enumerate( dataLoader[ phase]): how do I pass the new σ? Thanks. DatatLoader has a __setattr__ function. Is this the way and then automatically the new σ will be passed to the DataSet? In the DataSet I handle the σ already if it is passed.

Comment: From what I understand you need to have data generated with different sigma after every epoch? It would be much easier if you could share some code or literature regarding this.

Comment: I updated my question. I hope it makes clearer what I am asking about.